# Setting and Getting SignalR Caller properties in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, signalr

In the [SignalR Chat sample](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/samples/SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.Samples/Hubs/Chat/Chat.cs), Caller properties are set using the code;

```
Caller.name = newUser.Name;
```

Then later on, this property is read;

```
string name = Caller.name;
```

I have my own SignalR project, but this one is vb.net, and when i do the same setting and getting of the Caller properties, it doesn't work

```
Public Sub SetCaller()
    Caller.name = "tim"
End Sub

Public Sub GetCaller()
    Dim name as string = Caller.name
End Sub
```

GetCaller() throws an error of "Conversion from type 'Task(Of Object)' to type 'String' is not valid."

The exact same code, but in c# works fine;

```
public void SetCaller(){
    Caller.name = "tim";
}

public void GetCaller(){
    string name = Caller.name;
}
```

Is my code wrong in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not doing anything wrong syntactically in VB.NET.  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to check, using the IDE, what type Caller is and Caller.name.  In VB.NET, it is not case sensitive and many namespaces may be automatically imported without you specifically listing them at the top of the file, so it's quite possible that, in VB, it's using a different type for those than what you expect.

Comment: Caller is SignalR.Hubs.StatefulSignalAgent in both vb.net and c#

Comment: And what is the type of the name property?

Comment: I can't access that as it is a dynamic object?

Comment: That's interesting.  So when you set the name property to a string in C#, the dynamic property gets created with a type of string, but when you do the same thing in VB.NET, it gets created with a type of Type(Of Object)?  I'm not that familiar with the dynamic stuff, so unfortunately I can't help you further.

Comment: I recommend trying to reduce the problem down to the least amount of code possible.  Create your own class that has dynamic properties in the same way as StatefulSignalAgent does.  And then repost your question in a more general, why doesn't this dynamic object work properly kind of way.  I suspect if you do that, and you show all the code necessary to reproduce the problem, that you will get answers.  There's probably a lot more people here that know dynamic objects (me not included) than are familiar with that SignalR library.

Comment: Yeah I am just doing that right now. Stripping it right down to the basics to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering like me, I have found the answer. For VB.NET, we must use `Clients.CallerState.name`.